# How to vectorize matrix subsetting such that find() returns a matrix?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

Given a matrix `A`, I need to find the indices corresponding to the values 1 and 2. I could do this sequentially as follows:

```
>> B

B =

     1     2     3
     4     1     6
     7     8     9
     4     5     1

>> find(B==1)

ans =

     1
     6
    12

>> find(B==2)

ans =

     5
```

But if I do this kind of operation in a loop, Matlab will only use one core of my processor. How can I vectorise it, so that I obtain a matrix from `find`? I want this result:

```
>> my_find( B, [1 2] )

ans =

    1 5
    6 0
   12 0
```

(or some other padding)

How can I obtain this?

Comment: How flexible are you with your data format? If a cell array is ok, you could try arrayfun(@(x) find(B==x), [1 2], 'UniformOutput', false)

Comment: @mars Thanks! I suppose I can figure out how to obtain the matrix from there.

Comment: Using `find` will not make MATLAB use more CPU cores - [here is a list](http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN) of internal functions that *can* benefit from parallelism. So you might as well use a loop.

Comment: To look-up multiple values in an array use `ismember`, e.g. `[tf,loc]=ismember(B,[1 2])`. However that doesn't meet your output requirements (and in this case is almost trivial). And I doubt it will be multi-threaded anyhow.

Comment: Why does `find(B==1 | B==2)` not suffice? Or even, if your application allows it, skip the `find` and just use logical indices: `B==1 | B==2`. Sadly I don't think this will be done in parallel...you'll have to write your own MEX file for that I'm afraid.

Comment: Also, I assume you've got some bigger matrices to compare? Because the overhead of starting two threads would probably make this *slower* than the single-threaded version for matrices this small...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis They are around 1e5 x 100.

Answer (score 6):

Just don't use `find`

```
B==1

ans =

 1     0     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     1

B==2

ans =

 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     0
```

And then add or logical OR those together.

i.e.

```
(B==1) + (B==2)

ans =

 1     1     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     1
```

or

```
(B==1) | (B==2)

ans =

 1     1     0
 0     1     0
 0     0     0
 0     0     1
```

Comment: +1, Although I would recommend to use `&` instead of `+` so that the data type remains logical.

Comment: actually would need be a logical or `|` in this case

Comment: yes that is correct. I had earlier written `&` or `|` to emphasize on logical operation, but while editing removed the wrong one :)

Answer (score 0):

[i, j] = ind2sub(size(B), find(logical(sum(bsxfun(@eq, B(:), [1 2]), 2))))

Comment: With this, I don't think it's possible to discern which ones matched `1` and which ones matched `2`.

Comment: Sure it is; just split it up into more than one line: Bprime = B(:); inds = find(logical(sum(bsxfun(@eq, Bprime, [1 2]), 2))); Bprime(inds) will give you the value that matched each returned index in inds.